# How to set the date format to dd/MM/YYYY for entire application in C#

Tags: c#, date-format, cultureinfo

We are generating few csv's when we have fr-FR culture then date will be dd/mm/yyyy
But when we have en-US culture date format will be mm/dd/yyyy.
How to set the date format to dd/mm/yyyy irrespective of culture.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentCulture`

Comment: set your `globalization culture="en-GB"` in `Web.config` if its a web-app or `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");` if its a desktop app

Comment: What I read out of this is that you do have to have different Culture Settings and you need to keep those, is that right? But specific date renderings must be in _one_ specific format, is that right, too? (Just to be clear on the requirements here)

Comment: However you change the DateTime into a string (we don't know because you don't show) for this either give the format you want to have to whatever method you use or the CultureInfo with the format you want to use for that.

Comment: Do you use any CSV-Helper Libraries?

Comment: Sidenote make sure you actually want something culture specific. CSV is a typically exchange format and you mostly don't control all ends. So one should use a culture independent format here (ISO8601) and what you called US format is the invariant culture format actually.

Comment: @Ralf Microsoft messed us up bad when they decided to make `InvariantCulture` use `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of RFC 3339 or ISO 8601 - now we're stuck with it for eternity, _le sigh_.

Comment: Actually in my local system format is fr-FR and date format is dd/mm/YYYY.and we are uploading the csv's to Sharepoint and its opening without any issues.
But in server the format is en-US.If i put the same code to server the dates are in the format mm/dd/yyyy in this format files are not opening in sharepoint.